# Gestión permiso administrador para usuario remoto

Tags: windows10, permisos, panel-de-administracion

Tengo el siguiente problema, somos un grupo de personas trabajando en remoto y por políticas de seguridad debemos tener en los equipos de Windows 10 un usuario (que no es administrador) desde el cual trabajamos, y un usuario administrador que únicamente el responsable conoce la contraseña.

El problema consiste por ejemplo, cuando quiero instalar la actualización de un programa, me pide la contraseña de administrador del equipo. Al final el administrador, o jefe de equipo tiene que proporcionar la contraseña para poder realizar dicha acción.

Hemos probado hacer la gestión con varios programas de escritorios compartidos, pero siempre que se solicita la contraseña de administrador, se oculta en el escritorio remoto (Que es el Administrador). Los programas usados han sido Windows Desktop Remote, Anydesk, Supremo.

No sé si existe una manera mejor de gestionar este aspecto, agradezco de antemano todos los comentarios y ayudas. Espero que la explicación haya quedado lo más clara posible.

Comment: A priori esto es el estándar, es bastante incomodo al principio pero no hay mucho mas que hacer, un equipo se encarga de permitirte instalar ciertos programas o actualizarlos. Si cada uno tiene libertad para hacer lo que quiera los riesgos a nivel de seguridad se vuelven imposibles de controlar. Lo ideal es que los dispositivos os los den "planchados" con los programas que necesitáis usar ya preinstalados

Comment: Si, entiendo el estándar, por seguridad, etc. La cosa está en que, el propio administrador pueda proporcionar esta clave al equipo sin desplazarse insitu donde se encuentre el equipo y que además el usuario local del equipo, en este caso el trabajador, "a priori" no pueda ver la contraseña usada. He comentado más abajo como he conseguido resolver este flujo de gestión. Pero gracias a todos por los aportes.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a usar TightVNC Server para los usuarios "básicos" y TightVNC Viewer para el usuario "Admin", cuándo el usuario "básico" tenga que hacer cualquier cosa que deba permitir el usuario admin, únicamente el admin deberá conectarse remotamente y poner la contraseña, sin necesidad de proporcionarla.

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, lo probaré!

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Finalmente he conseguido solventar la problemática de esta gestión. Cada usuario tiene su cuenta en su propio equipo proporcionado por la empresa, este equipo también cuenta con una cuenta de administrador (Jefe de equipo), los equipos se entregan con los programas a usar instalados desde la cuenta admin. Uno de estos programas es anydesk, el cual el administrador por interactuar de manera remota en la sesión del usuario local, proporcionando así el password de administrador escondido por *****, cuando este se requiera para actualizaciones, por ejemplo